# Groovy class factory pattern gives weird error

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am new to groovy and I am trying with some groovy code. I have this scenario. I have the following modules

```
package com.utils

abstract class Base {

    static String data = ''

}
```

```
package com.utils

class A extends Base {

    static String data = 'dummy'

}
```

```
package com.utils

class B extends Base {

    static String data = 'dummy'

}
```

```
package com.utils

class ShapeFactory {
    static Map <String,Object> shapes = [
        "a": A,
        "b": B
    ]

    static Object get_shapes(String shape) {
        return shapes.get(shape);
    }
}

And in the main file I am using
```

and in the main file and here is where it fails with weird error. I couldn't identify the reason, I would appreciate any help.

```
import com.utils.ShapeFactory

def shapeA = ShapeFactory.get_shapes('a')

shapeA.data // here it fails with the below error
```

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.Map' 
due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map()
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The error is not arising from any of the code that you've shared. If you copy-paste in into a Groovy console, it runs without error

Comment: Yeah, also unable to reproduce with any 3.x or 2.x version of groovy. Please provide a code example that results in the error you are describing, preferably with the `groovy -v` output attached so we know what versions of java and groovy you are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I found the issue, In the Base class I had a Map variable as well which was initialized as an array

```
abstract class Base {
   static String data = ''
   static Map mapper = []  // This has to be [:]
}
```